# How to access an Elastic Beanstalk Environment from EB CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm learning more about Elastic Beanstalk and for that I'm trying to practice the tutorials in the amazon website.
I first did the [python-django](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/projects/deploy-python-application/) application tutorial which was all done using EB CLI. Now I'm doing the [Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-dynamodb-tutorial.html) tutorial. I created the environment using the console, but I'm not able to understand how to access it using EB CLI. I searched in Amazon website but couldn't find anything relevant.

Any help?

Comment: The reference documentation for managing Elastic Beanstalk via the awscli is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html and from the EB CLI is at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html. What are you having problems with?

Comment: I've configured the EB CLI. When I use the Elastic Beanstalk console to launch an Elastic Beanstalk environment, I can't access the environment or the application I deployed from the EB CLI. I can only access it when I create  an Environment using CLI. I'm not sure if I need to run some command to acess the console created Envs via the CLI.

Comment: Not much information provided here, but I would guess that you have created a Beanstalk env in one region (using the console) but are trying to manage it in another region (using the cli). Or you are using AWS credentials with the cli that are from a different AWS account.

Comment: Nope, it's same region and same account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the source code that is deployed to your Beanstalk environment from the console:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/home?region=REGION#/application/versions?applicationName=APPLICATION_NAME

. . . but replace REGION and APPLICATION_NAME with the region and app name you're working on. The 'Source' column has a link to the ZIP file that was uploaded to S3. Clicking the link will download the source code to your local computer.

From there, after you unzip your files, you can set up a new workspace with `eb init`. The wizard should give you the option to select your existing Application and Environment.

If you want to associate an existing workspace at a new Environment that's possible too. You'll need to check to make sure your workspace is configured with the right application name.

```
% cd .elasticbeanstalk
% vi config.yml
```

Look for . . .

```
global:
  application_name: APPLICATION_NAME
```

You can modify this file with the correct application name. Then navigate to the root of your project and change the Beanstalk environment.

```
% eb list
% eb use ENVIRONMENT_NAME_FROM_LIST
```

The check the status to ensure that everything is configured correctly.

```
% eb status
```

Hope that helps! Good luck!